# MySQL client for large databases

Tags: mysql, client

I wanto to get a MySQL client for large databases. Some tables have three million rows. I've tried some clients, but all of them give "run out of memory" when I want to get all of the rows from the large tables. Please give me idea what mysql client is the best for me?
And a plus condition is the good speed of queries

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with mysql console? (In other words - what's the 'client' you're looking for supposed to do?)

Comment: Even if you want to display 3 millon rows they will not be able to consume it, so use pagination.

Comment: This would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185/what-is-the-best-mysql-client-application-for-windows

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't fetch 3 million rows in one go.  It doesn't matter what client you use - the machine will be what's preventing you from getting all the rows.  Instead, you should fetch the rows in batches.

Comment: I can't agree enough with this - you need to re-evaluate why you need 3 million rows at once and consider if there's a better option.

Answer (score 0):

There are some GUI tools out there.

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/slideshows/top-10-mysql-gui-tools.html

But like others said, you have to fetch the data in smaller parts.